# Error al usar openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, oledb

Tengo un problema con respecto al `openrowset`.

Estoy ejecutando la siguiente codificación:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Procesos\PRUEBA.xlsx', [Hoja1$])
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

> El proveedor OLE DB 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no puede usarse para consultas distribuidas porque está configurado para ejecutarse en el modo de subprocesamiento controlado simple.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, antes debes correr las sentencias siguientes para que se permita tu tipo de consulta. Espero que te funcione:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: Hola si mande este comando pero aun sale el mismo error